# Why does it say my project is targeting MSIL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

My project, "VmmCsTest" is configured with Platform target: x64.

So why then does MSBuild say "the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" in the following warning message?

5>------ Build started: Project: VmmCsTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5> ... :warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\1\Information\bin\x64\Debug\Information.dll", "AMD64". ...

Okay, so I debug the tests, and I get this:

A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Invoking x64 from a 64 bit process should work, so I'm guessing something is forcing the test to run as a 32 bit process.  How do I figure out what the problem file is?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can set the default processor achitecture to x64

[image]

I think that will sove your problem.

Comment: I didn't know about this, may be helpful. I ended up undoing the project settings so I could continue working, but I will try this in future.